# In Shiny, how do you output a histogram if the selected variable is numeric and a barplot if it is categorical?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

In Shiny, how do you output a histogram if the selected variable is numeric and a barplot if it is categorical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a logic which variables are numeric and which are categorical, then you can make different plots:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "variable",
              label = "Variable",
              choices = colnames(mtcars)),
  h3(""),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$variable)
    g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = !!as.symbol(input$variable)))
      if (input$variable %in% c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec")) {
        # numeric
        g <- g + geom_histogram()
      } else {
        # categorical
        g <- g + geom_bar()
      }
    
    g
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```